# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - May 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the eighth edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for May 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      420
2   Monomeeth                  380
3   Nimesh Neema               290
4   bmike                      110
5   grg                        100
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,565 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-05-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema             114
2   Monomeeth                 65
3   Matt                      52
4   bmike                     49
5   Pang, Allan               47
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,477
2   Monomeeth                 720
3   Nimesh Neema              453
4   bmike                     177
5   grg                       128
```

A big thank you to all 60 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   dwightk                   55
2   Allan                     54
3   Mark                      43
4   nohillside                38
5   Monomeeth                 30
```

A big thank you to all 17 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema             271
2   Monomeeth                255
3   Allan                    125
4   fsb                       90
5   grg                       63
```

A big thank you to all 33 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    124
2   Nimesh Neema              51
3   Monomeeth                 48
4   Glorfindel                33
5   fsb, Scot                 18
```

A big thank you to all 28 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     77
2   Monomeeth                 22
3   Nimesh Neema              21
4   fsb                       19
5   Scot                      16
```

A big thank you to all 19 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    19
2   Monomeeth                11
3   fsb                       9
4   Mark                      7 
5   dwightk                   6
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    85
2   Monomeeth                74
3   Nimesh Neema             53
4   dwightk                  28
5   nohillside               22
```

A big thank you to all 42 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [A tech from MacKeeper wishes access to my computer for licensing and activation. Is this a scam?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325359/a-tech-from-mackeeper-wishes-access-to-my-computer-for-licensing-and-activation)

   - Posted by: Jerry Boutet
   - Votes: **66**
2. [How can I get two calculators going?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325420/how-can-i-get-two-calculators-going)

   - Posted by: dr_bubble_pops
   - Votes: **28**
3. [How can I add a custom message in the macOS login screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324873/how-can-i-add-a-custom-message-in-the-macos-login-screen)

   - Posted by: user288374
   - Votes: **23**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [A tech from MacKeeper wishes access to my computer for licensing and activation. Is this a scam?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325364/168832)

   - Posted by: Allan
   - Votes: **208**
2. [A tech from MacKeeper wishes access to my computer for licensing and activation. Is this a scam?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325370/168832)

   - Posted by: l008com
   - Votes: **91**
3. [A tech from MacKeeper wishes access to my computer for licensing and activation. Is this a scam?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325392/168832)

   - Posted by: Stilez
   - Votes: **53**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [A tech from MacKeeper wishes access to my computer for licensing and activation. Is this a scam?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325359/a-tech-from-mackeeper-wishes-access-to-my-computer-for-licensing-and-activation)

   - Posted by: Jerry Boutet
   - Views: **19,927**
2. [WhatsApp doesn’t show usernames on notifications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325672/whatsapp-doesn-t-show-usernames-on-notifications)

   - Posted by: Javier Mateos
   - Views: **14,326**
3. [How can I get two calculators going?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325420/how-can-i-get-two-calculators-going)

   - Posted by: dr_bubble_pops
   - Views: **6,069**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [dwightk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/70930/dwightk)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Jerry Boutet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/289001/jerry-boutet)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Jerry Boutet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/289001/jerry-boutet)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In May our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 471 flags with an average handling time of 26 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 165 comments
- deleted 239 posts
- closed 155 posts
- edited 176 posts
- created 129 posts
- created 430 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: Thanks for compiling @Monomeeth!

Answer (score 5):

Pretty humbling to see all the moderation, support and collaboration that happens here on a routine basis.

Well done to everyone concerned!

Comment: Indeed, sometimes I think I spend too much time here, then these stats remind me I'm not... hah!